# In Sweetalert2, how to use inputted data in php?

Tags: php, post, input, sweetalert2

I want to be able to use data submitted via input: 'text' in php. If I post via ajax, the data is shown in the console, but there seems to be no way to use it in php. It can also be shown in a div, but again, that seems to be useless as far as actually using the inputted data. I've tried posting as json as well. I've searched and searched, and maybe I missed something, but can find no solution. Every post I've seen addressing this issue uses ajax to post to a php page, but the page does not come up after submitting, and the data is only available in the console.

For example, this code posts to a page called "discount.php", but after submitting, it stays on the page it was on, and there is no way I see to access the inputted data:

```
var CustomerKey = 1234;//your customer key value.
Swal.fire({
    title: "Add Note",
    input: "textarea",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#1FAB45",
    confirmButtonText: "Save",
    cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
    buttonsStyling: true
}).then(function () {       
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "discount.php",
        data: { 'CustomerKey': CustomerKey},
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            Swal.fire(
            "Sccess!",
            "Your note has been saved!",
            "success"
            )
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            Swal.fire(
            "Internal Error",
            "Oops, your note was not saved.", // had a missing comma
            "error"
            )
        }
    });
}, 
function (dismiss) {
  if (dismiss === "cancel") {
    swal(
      "Cancelled",
        "Canceled Note",
      "error"
    )
  }
})
```

If I am missing something, I hope someone can explain it to me. Thanks!

Comment: You can return data in your `discount.php`, this is then made available in `response` in either your `success` or your `error` callback  (the `failure` callback does not exist by the way, https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/) of your `$.ajax()` call. Just add a `console.log(response);` inside both callback functions and see what it returns from `discount.php`

Comment: php variables are interpreted when page loads, you can't change them with ajax afterwards, so like @Johannes wrote, you can make some calculations in discount.php, return them in an ajax response and use it with javascript